# In Vuex + Jest, how to unit test a getter which is calling the store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, jestjs

I'm trying to test the following very simple getter from my vuex store. It is simply concatenating two strings :

```js
const getters = {
  adressToGet: state => {
    return state.baseAdress + store.getters.queryToGet
  }
 }
```

Mocking the state part is easy but I can't find a good way to mock the store.

If this was in a component, I could mount the component with `mount` or `shallow` and assign to it the mock store, but it isn't. This is from the vuex store.

This is my test code :

```js
import Search from '@/store/modules/search'

jest.mock('@/store/modules/search.js')

describe('search.js', () => {

  test('The adress getter gets the right adress', () => {
    const state = {
      baseAdress: 'http://foobar.com/'
    }
    // I define store here, but how can I inject it into my tested getter ?
    const store = { 
      getters: {
        queryToGet: 'barfoo'
      }
    }
    expect(Search.getters.adressToGet(state)).toBe('http://foobar.com/barfoo')
  })
})
```

I get `http://foobar.com/undefined` instead of expected.

What would be the best way to do this ?

**Edit: Following the first comment, my new version, but it still gives the same result:**

```js
import Search from '@/store/modules/search'
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

jest.mock('@/store/modules/search.js')

describe('search.js', () => {

  test('The adress getter gets the right adress', () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuex)

    const mockState = {
      baseAdress: 'http://foobar.com/'
    }

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: mockState,
      getters: {
        queryToGet: function () {
          return 'barfoo'
        }
      }
    }) 

   expect(Search.getters.adressToGet(mockState))
   .toBe('http://foobar.com/barfoo')
  })
})
```

Comment: I think it'd be fine to define it as `const store = new Vuex.Store(store)` before the assertion. However, to avoid scope pollution you should before create a local Vue instance for the test itself. I mean something like: 

`import { createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)`

Comment: I edited the code on the question to reflect your changes, but sadly the output is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much research, I realized I had to mock the store dependency with Jest. This seems the correct way to do it and pass the test:

```js
import Search from '@/store/modules/search'

jest.mock('@/store/index.js', () =>({
  getters: {
    queryToGet: 'barfoo'
  }
}))

jest.mock('@/store/modules/search.js')

describe('search.js', () => {
  test('The adress getter gets the right adress', () => {
    const state = {
      baseAdress: 'http://foobar.com/'
    }
    expect(Search.getters.adressToGet(state))
    .toBe('http://foobar.com/barfoo')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been bashing my head against the wall for 2 days now, because of vuex!

Comment: How to change the mocked value later to test if it changes accordingly?

Comment: @trainoasis You're probably looking for mockReturnValueOnce https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions